# Where can I find more resources that explain Bitcoin simply?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, learning

I have been learning crypto for a little bit now and have been helped a lot by pebwindkraft, Andrew Chow and Adam in particular.

I would like to ask about resources that help beginners like me to understand the crypto space, I have been following a guy on youtube and I believe that he deserves some credit for the github book he did and the youtube videos that explain bitcoin in a way that I can sort of understand.

If you have any other resources then please feel free to put them down below.

Edit:

The channel I was referring was : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHBWzcGSrtoLYcasLwGvsow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you reading Mastering bitcoin book first and second editions. It's exactly what you are looking for.

https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook

if you like watching more than reading this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXUTUhERJUE&list=PLmL13yqb6OxdEgSoua2WuqHKBuIqvll0x) videos are amazing

Comment: Thanks Adam, You may not remember me, but you have helped a ton too. I am actually reading that book as well, I somewhat prefer visuals, so was hoping for a organised "series"

Comment: I have edited my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Watched one or two and they are really good. Thanks for the link, I hope others can post more resources too

Answer (score 0):

There is a TON of info out there, so I think one of the biggest issues for beginners is finding *good* information, since they may not yet understand the difference between good and bad info in this space.  I think it is very important for users to form at least a basic understanding of what cryptocurrencies are, and what sort of problems they solve, so that they can make informed decisions.

I often recommend people take a look at [Jameson Lopp's bitcoin resource page](https://lopp.net/bitcoin.html), it is an awesome list for just about anyone involved in bitcoin to take a look at.

If you are looking for technical details, [Andreas' book *Mastering Bitcoin*](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook) is one of the best resources out there. His youtube videos are also great, and much more accessible for a non-technical audience.

And of course this website is great for specific questions! I've learned a lot just browsing through old Qs/As, there is some great knowledge stored away here.

Comment: Thanks for the links, and you are 100% right about being able to differentiate between bad and good information. It's also hard to spot when the author is wrong because we don't know ourselves

Answer (score 0):

The best place to go would be [CryptoInfluence](http://cryptoinfluence.io)

They rank I think 90% of all YouTube channels over 1k subscribers in the CryptoSpace. Its done on their stats, and also a community poll. The top guys are usually most worth your time...but you can find some real gems in the middle or even near the bottom.

They also have a scam list that tells you which YouTube channels to avoid!

Also, I was recommended an "Into to Bitcoin" book written by a Dr. Julian Hosp. It even comes with a work booklet, so you can quiz yourself on the terms. Doctor Hosp also has a YouTube channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/julianhosp