# Balance zero after recovering wallet from seed-phrase

Tags: blockchain, wallet, wallet-recovery, e-wallet, breadwallet

I recently got help my some experts on how i can recover my wallet using my private key, so i went ahead and downloaded brd wallet and block chain, then proceeded to recover wallet in the first and recover funds in the latter, but both brought up my account with zero funds in it.

I am a bit confused and worried now as i just made that payment i dont know how i can go about it, and secondly if i get the Qr code of my old wallet and i scan it into blockchain addresses and it comes up as non- spendable, and i am being told to scan my private key if i have it in written how can i go about unlocking that...

---

Original question: [I forgot which software I created my wallet with. How can I recover from a 12 word seed phrase?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/78940/i-forgot-which-software-i-created-my-wallet-with-how-can-i-recover-from-a-12-wo),

Answer (score 1):

> **I ... downloaded BRD wallet ... then proceeded to recover wallet ... but [it] brought up my account with zero funds in it.**

- Choose `Sync Blockchain` (`Menu` > `Settings` > `Sync Blockchain`).
- Wait five hours
- Check balance

If not try

- Uninstall Bread Bitcoin Wallet.
- Reinstall Bread Bitcoin Wallet.
- Bread will ask you to type in your 12-word key in order to re-instate your Bread Wallet.
- Now your balance should show as $0.00. This is normal.
- Sync Blockchain (Menu > Settings > Sync Blockchain). Note: takes several hours.
- Bitcoin balance should now be displayed properly.

From https://www.reidwalley.com/fix-bread-bitcoin-wallet-not-importing-paper-wallet/

Comment: There is no Sync blockchain in the settings menu

Comment: I had done that, but it was still Zero Let me try again and bring a feedback with 7 hours, but on blockchain also what can i do, i am trying both apps

Answer (score 0):

Your recovery phrase 12 words will help you only to get your HD wallet back

The old addresses (imported addresses will not be recovered)

If you have an old blockcjain account make sure you have the recovery password phrase (16 words)